# public private key solution for javascript and python

Tags: javascript, python, encryption, pgp

I'm looking for a public private key solution that I can use with a javascript client and python backend. The aim is to send data encrypted from the client to the server... Are the any solutions? Thanks for hints.

Comment: SSL? As in, just use an https connection?

Answer (score 0):

Use SSL for your connections to the server. Probably the easiest way to do that is to use HTTP for communication and also to run a proxy (say, Apache) on the server that can do HTTPS and forwards requests to the actual server application.

Comment: Nginx can do this too, might be more lightweight, just a reverse proxy doing the SSL